# Diferença entre WebApi e SPA

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, single-page-application

Sei que `SPA` nada mais é do que um `WebApi` específico, mas a pergunta é: Como eu diferencio um do outro, ou seja, qual a finalidade de cada um no mundo Desenvolvimento. Pra que eu desenvolveria um `SPA` ao invés de um `WebApi`?

Creio que a pergunta não está ampla, pois eu quero saber a diferença entre ambos.

Answer (score 2):

Na verdade são dois escopos bem diferentes.

**SPA**, ou *[single-page application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application)*, é uma definição de comportamento de interface com o usuário onde não ocorrem reloads do conteúdo, apenas trocas parciais - de maneira muito similar à uma aplicação *desktop* típica. Seu domínio é o *front-end*.

**WebAPI** é uma definição de implementação de funcionalidades *server-side*. A grande maioria das implementações WebAPI são [RESTful](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/REST), porém isso não é mandatório. Seu domínio é o *back-end*.

A implementação dos dois em paralelo é possível - uma interface SPA (por exemplo em *Angular*) acessando recursos disponibilizados via WebAPI.